# Convert db response to boolean in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Background**

I am writing a simple function that queries some table

**Code**

```
def get_status() -> bool:
    status = db.run_query(
        ENVIRONMENT="prod",
        sql="SELECT status FROM status_table",
    )
    print(status) #[Record(status=False)]
    print(type(status)) # <class 'list'>
    if str((status[0].is_delivery_creation_in_process)) == "True":
        return True
    return False
```

**Issue**

Is there a way to convert this type of response to a bool rather than a string and do comparaision in python? My solution does not feel pythonic but i am not able to see or come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

`bool("False")` and `bool("True")` both return `True` as they are both not empty strings

you could do something like this

```py
a = "False"

print(bool(a.replace("False","")))
# returns False
```

to remove `False` from the string which will make it return `False`

if you can only receive `True` and `False` then you can instead slice the string (remove last/first 4 characters) and the reverse will happen: `False` will end up with only 1 character and `True` will end up with none, returning `False`

code for this is:

```py
a = "True"

print(bool(a[:-4]))
# returns False
```